# Copy S3 bucket to E2E Object Storage using MinIO Client

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage, e2e, minio-client

I want to Copy S3 bucket Object to E2E Object Storage using MinIO Client.

I can't figure out how to configure and copy, some things i tried using official doc of minio client.

Referral Links

https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc.html

```
mc alias set S3 https://mybucketname.s3... access_key secret_key
mc alias set E2E https://objectstorage.s3... access_key secret_key
```

then for copy object using recursion

```
mc cp --recursive S3/ E2E/
```